# How should I create an instance of my repository if I'm not using a generic interface?

Tags: design-patterns

I've decided not to use a generic interface for my various repositories. Instead, I have an interface for each repository with a "real" repository and a mock repository inheriting each one. Does this mean I'll need a separate factory class for each repository as well?

If there's a better design decision I can make here, I'd love to hear it.

```
IPersonRepository

PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
PersonRepositoryMock : IPersonRepository
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll mean either separate factory classes for each repository or a single factory that has separate create methods for each one.  That's one consequence of your decision.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to setup the Di Container to use the 'real' repository with your app and the fake with the tests.

Or better yet, use a mock library so you don't need a repository mock. However an in-memory repo will help a lot with devel as you can create tests (which can be later used for the real repo) and see the app in action without touching the db.